# How to subset RData file that is too large for memory?

Tags: r, memory, bigdata

I have an RData file that has become too large to load on my computer using the `load()` command. It contains a data frame with ~3 million observations and ~100 variables.

I want to

- load the file, maybe using some bigdata or ff package (but I have no idea how these work)
- get rid of some variables to reduce file size
- save it as as an Rdata file with a regular data frame (not some weird "bigdata" type object)
- use `load()` to load the condensed file and resume regular R operations

How should I go about this?

Comment: If the data.frame doesn't fit into memory, you are out of luck. How did you create the file?

Comment: On a better (64-bit) computer.

Comment: Wel, then go back there and save as a text file or in a database.

Comment: Fire up an AWS instance and load it first, then parcel it out.

Comment: I have not tried this out, so I am leaving this as a comment. But I think the ``archivist`` package (https://cran.r-project.org/package=archivist) could help here. See: http://smarterpoland.pl/index.php/2014/09/lazy-load-with-archivist/

Answer (score 0):

last week Jared Lander (author of the book "R for Everyone") helped is in creating a R tint on a bigboards.io hex. We installed RStudio Server on it and we use the whole storage/processing capabilities of the hex. Ceph is used to distribute the data on the nodes

Anyway, it feels like a solution for your question.

Comment: Tint and Hex are proprietary terms from the BigBoards company meaning "software" and "hexagonal hardware device… a cluster of 6 nodes [each with its own CPU]" according to http://bigboards-docs.readthedocs.org/en/stable/ The opaque jargon makes this answer a bit unclear, more or less amounts to the comments above, 'get a better computer' and use RStudio Server. Tutorial/link to more info ?